# Что находится через пробел после ssh ключа

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, mac

У меня в файле `id_rsa.pub` находится следующий текст:

```
ssh-rsa MY_SSH_KEY Ivanov
```

Очевидно, что я когда-то вводил 'Ivanov' как какой-то параметр.
Что это такое? Часть ключа или какое-то имя ключа?

Comment: имя компьютера обычно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это комментарий.

`$ man ssh-keygen`
:

```
-C comment
        Provides a new comment.
```

Тест:

`$ ssh-keygen -C "TEST"`

`$ cat id_rsa.pub`
:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA...eywd TEST
```